# a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' error while json.dump

Tags: python, json, python-3.7

I'm trying to dump a dict into a JSON file. The code attached below works in python 2 but I get the above mentioned error when I try running it on python 3.

```
import json
for terr_item in data:    
    with open( 'influence_data/' + str(terr_item['territory_id']) +'-influence.json','wb') as f:
        json.dump(terr_item,f,ensure_ascii=False,allow_nan=False,indent=4)
```

EDIT :

I tried to write using 'w' as well but then I get a 
'Object of type Int64 is not JSON serializable'

Comment: string and bytes of python 3 is different from python 2 (https://webkul.com/blog/string-and-bytes-conversion-in-python3-x/) so you would need to use decode and decode. Because you use `wb` to open the file in binary you can use `rb` to read it. But i would just use `"w"` instead of `"wb"` as there are no reason to use binary mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3, a *binary* output file must receive byte string instead of the normal Python3 unicode strings.

Here you have no reason to use the binary mode, so you should use:

```
with open( 'influence_data/' + str(terr_item['territory_id']) +'-influence.json','w') as f:
    json.dump(terr_item,f,ensure_ascii=False,allow_nan=False,indent=4)
```